# How does view encapsulation work in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have 6 components hm1 to hm6_component.ts  Each component has it's own stylesheet hm1 to hm6_compoent.css

I also have style.css that contains common styles for all 6 components. I add that in angular.json  I understand style.css will be loaded  when the user  visits any of these 6 components

hm1, hm2 and hm3 components use a few common styles those are not used by hm4, hm5, and hm6 components.  I would like to put these styles in a new file common123.css and I want this file to be loaded only if the user visits any of hm1, hm2 or hm3 component and loaded ONLY ONCE. So if the user visits hm1 component, common123.css will be loaded but if the user visits hm2 subsequently, common123.css should be available to hm2 and should not be loaded again. Also if the user visits hm5 component then common123.css should not be loaded.  How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this approach.

1. At first, create a new css file, common123.css and add the common styles used by h1, h2, and h3 components.
2. In each of the h1, h2, and h3 components, import common123.css in their respective component stylesheets (ex: h1_component.css, h2_component.css, and h3_component.css).
3. In angular.json file, add common123.css to the "styles" array, which includes the common stylesheets for all components. Make sure to add it **BEFORE** the style.css file like below.

```json
"build": {
    "options": {
        ...
        "styles": [
          "src/styles/common123.css",
          "src/styles/style.css"
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
},
```

By following these steps, common123.css will be loaded when the user visits any of the h1, h2, or h3 components. The common styles will be applied to these components along with their individual component styles. The styles in common123.css will not be applied to h4, h5, or h6 components since it is not included in their respective component stylesheets or in the global style.css.

Hope this answer would help you even a bit.

Comment: all the files you include in angular.json are bundle (with the .css in the components) in an unique bundle file that is to all the application). When we use .css in a component without ViewEncapsultion.None, the only Angular make is add to all the class in .css the "selector" of the component. This is the reason this .css defined in a component only applied to the component, but there're an **unique** file.css

Comment: @Eliseo so is there a way to dynamically add css as the user surf through the pages ?  I am  trying to make the app bundle as small as possible. I could probably dynamically add css to head section of html  using js  but I was wondering if there is a built in facility within angular.  What louis proposed would work but I think all the classes will get added to the initial bundle.

Comment: @marcg, To add a .css dinamicallly, check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73521654/how-to-dynamically-load-css-with-angular/73525150#73525150)

Comment: @marcg, complementary I founded this [SO](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config) if you want to create different bundles for the .css