# How can I style the active and centered slide in ngx owl carousel in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, owl-carousel, ng-template

I've been a few days now trying to understand how can I style my .active.center slide that was generated by the Ngx Owl Carousel structural directive.

As you can see in the image below, I have a .owl-item.active.center that was generated by the template part `<ng-template carouselSlide>`. I just want to know how can I style it, because I am not being able to access it directly using `.owl-item.active.center`.

[image: Active Center tag in Owl Item]

Below is my attempt.

My Template:

```
<!-- Testimonials Carousel. Data is sent from TypeScript.
 "Change" event generates SlidesOutputData object - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-2#change
 Logic: Pass SlidesOutputData object to getData function. -->
<owl-carousel-o [options]="testimonialsCarousel" (change)="getData($event)" class="w-100">

  <!-- We can't apply styles to NgContainer directly. -->
  <ng-container *ngFor="let testimonial of testimonials">

    <!-- DOMs were rendered using carouselSlide structural directive. You can't apply directives/element attributes here.
    What I need: Get access and style slide object with attributes "Active" and "Center" -->
    <ng-template carouselSlide>

      <!-- Testimonial with Local Variable defined -->
      <article #testimonialarticle class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center
      shadow p-4 m-3 text-center testing-class">

        <!-- Insert image using Property Binding -->
        <figure><img class="img-circle" [src]="testimonial.avatar" [alt]="testimonial.avatarAlt"></figure>

        <!-- Syntax below is: Interpolation / Data Binding -->
        <p>{{testimonial.text}}</p>
        <p>{{testimonial.author}}</p>

      </article>
      <!-- End of Testimonial -->

    </ng-template>

  </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
```

My TypeScript:

```
// Carousel Class that uses OnInit
export class RowClientsComponent implements OnInit {
  // Etc
  testimonialsCarousel: OwlOptions = {
    center: true,
    dots: true,

    // Slide continuously
    autoplay: false,
    loop: true,

    // autoplayTimeout higher than autoplaySpeed | smartSpeed
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    smartSpeed: 1000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    items: 3
  }

  // Testimonials - 1. Define Interface, 2. Array of Type Interface
  testimonials: Testimonial[] = [
    // Data for Slides...
    // Etc...
  ]

  // New object of type "SlidesOutputData" that is generated after "Change" event.
  activeSlides?: SlidesOutputData = new SlidesOutputData; // ? - Can be null

  // Update activeSlides object with data sent from event defined in template
  // Ref. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-2#events
  getData(data: SlidesOutputData) {
    // Import data from SlidesOutputData to activeSlides - The `This` is the component class.
    this.activeSlides = data;

    // Loop through slides and check if any slide has center attribute true
    if (this.activeSlides && this.activeSlides.slides) {
      for (const slide of this["activeSlides"].slides) {
        if (slide.center === true) {
          console.log('Slide centralizado:', slide);

          // If it's centered - I want to add a class to it so I can style using the component CSS
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Inject reference to DOM element with @ViewChild and wrap it's native DOM element to nativeElement in @ElementRef
  @ViewChild('testimonialarticle')
  classArticle: ElementRef = new ElementRef('testimonialarticle');

  ngOnInit() {
    // Print "Testimonial Article" element using ElementRef wrapper, through his nativeElement property.
    console.log(this.classArticle);

    // Change background color of our article without accessing DOM element directly - Did'nt work.
    this.renderer.selectRootElement('#testimonialarticle').setStyle(this, "background-color", "black");
  }

  // Inject Renderer2 to avoid XSS attacks and direct access to DOM
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }
  // Etc
}
```

Comment: try put the .css in your styles.css (in a global .css that shared all the aplication)

Comment: The problem is that I have other carousels that will be affected by it.

Comment: Remember: use more specified selectors. e.g. if you enclosed all in a div with class="custom-carousel">, you can write `.custom-carousel div.owl-item....{...}`, only the carousel enclosed in a div with custom-carousel class use this class.

Comment: Yes. This works when applying the styles in the root CSS style `styles.css`, but I do  believe that as the software scales, centering all styles in the main `styles.css` file will cause some difficults to remain organized and well structured - Example, if I have too many custom styles, it's easier to keep each component style on its own CSS, instead of the global CSS file. I was able to achieve this by using `::ng-deep` on the component CSS, and another way was setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, but i'm finding a alternative since I found both solutions not in best practices.

Comment: `ViewEncapsulation.None` makes all the .css in your component global. I'm not pretty sure if [adding dinamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73521654/how-to-dynamically-load-css-with-angular/73525150#73525150) styles in your component, can be a good aproach.

Comment: But bootstrap, owl carousel, material and a lot of other components library do that... @Eliseo So if it's not a good approach to add dynamic styles we should just stop using those completelly.. I just want to style a already dynamic class that was added by a library (In my case Ngx Owl Carouse - But it applies to other as well like Angular Material and NG Bootstrap.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only two methods I was able to achieve this was by using `::ng-deep`, which is deprecated and the other way was to use the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` parameter inside my `@Component` decorator.

For now, this is how I did. But I am still looking for alternatives since I saw that neither solution is a good option.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-row-clients',
  templateUrl: './row-clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./row-clients.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Now without the encapsulation, I can style my component:

```
.testimonialcarousel .owl-item.active.center {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale3d(1.0, 1.0, 1);
}
```

I'm just not glad that I did'nt managed to use another more secure and recommended approach.